# retrieve dynamically assigned tcp port from akka.net remote

Tags: tcp, port, akka.net

My job is to write a distributed client/server application with some concurrent tasks. So i decided to use akka.net for the concurrency issues. To implement the ipc between server and client akka remote is used. For some reasons there may run more than one client of the same type on a workstation. So i configured these clients for dynamic assignment of a tcp port. This worked fine for sending messages to the server.

My problem is to push some information to the clients. To accomplish this task an actor on the client exist. Now the server creates a reference for this actor. Therefor it needs the port the client is listening on . My idea is to send the tcp port the client uses to the server in some sort of connection procedure using a actor on the server.

After searching for some hours I didn't find any hint where to find the dynamically assigned tcp port. So how would the client get the assigned tcp port?

Ok, I could use akka.cluster. But using akka.cluster is breaking a fly on the wheel, I think. And if it solves my issue reamins to be seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two suggestions, assuming that it is your client that makes the first contact with the server.

1. I'd have the server keep track of which clients are connected.  I'd probably have a heartbeat message that gets sent once every few seconds from each client system.  This way you can store an `IActorRef` for each alive client and send messages back without the need for finding the port.  `IActorRefs` are preferable wherever possible for location transparency.
2. If you actually need to explicitly find the port, you may be able to extract it from the `Path` property of the `IActorRef` of one of the actors on the client system.

Comment: Your assumtion is correct. The client sends a hello message to the designated server actor.

Comment: Ok, so if use the `Sender` property to get the `IActorRef` to the client, and keep track of which clients are connected, hopefully you won't need to find the port at all.

Comment: Sorry, took to long to edit...    Your assumtion is correct. The client sends a hello message to the designated server actor. How would i get an IActorRef for the client while executing the actor on the server? Is this done by the sender available while executing an actor? Would the actor sending the hartbeat have to handle the pushed information?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to patricks suggestions my issue is solved.

The solution is to extract the needed information from the senders path available while executing the hello message. With this information the server is able to maintain a list of all connected clients and theire network address.

Thanks a lot @ patrick.

Regards Gregor